# Accessing protocol methods without extending the protocol works in Swift 3 but not in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, extension-methods, swift-protocols

I was checking a crash issue in Swift 4 when it was found that a view controller in the existing code was using table view and its  delegate and datasource methods were implemented in the controller but the controller did not extend UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. The table's datasource and delegate were mapped to the controller through the storyboard. This issue was not noticed until we migrated to Swift 4 when the application started crashing.

What could be the reason that it worked until Swift 3? (I tested the older version and the application seems to be still working without breaking. But how?)

Swift 3:

```
    class DailyDealsViewController : UIViewController
{
 @IBOutlet weak var tblDailyDeals : UItableView!
     override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblDailyDeals.dataSource = self
    tblDailyDeals.delegate = self
}

 internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
 //write code to prepare your cell and return the cell
}
}
```

The above code does not extend UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate (I understand that ideally this should not be missing) but the delegate and datasource methods are triggered in Swift 3. This fails in Swift 4 and works only after the class extends these protocols. Please help me understand why this works in Swift 3 but not in Swift 4.

Comment: I would suggest to add some code to make it more clear...

Comment: Thanks @AhmadF , I have added some code.